# For SameSite cookie with subdomains what are considered the same site?

Tags: cookies, csrf

For the samesite cookie attribute I'm not clear on if I set a cookie with domain .example.com from sub.example.com with the samesite attribute, if it will be considered the same site as other.example.com.

Cookie behavior is different than CORS and I'm having trouble finding a resource that definitively clarifies this.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The 'Site' in SameSite refers to a the combination of second level domain ***mysite***.com and top level domain *mysite.**com***.

> This means that a requests from `login.mysite.com` to `cdn.mysite.com`
>   would be considered a same-site request.

**BUT**... as you might imagine it does not end there. There is the [Public Suffixes List](https://publicsuffix.org/learn/) which slightly changes this validation behavior.

Why? Well, because there are a number of sites where end users, and not the registrar or domain owner, control part of the domain (the sub-domain). 
E.g. `my-site.azurewebsites.net`.

From a privacy and security perspective cookies scoped to `my-site.azurewebsites.net` should definitely not be sent to `your-site.azurewebsites.net`. And, since there is no algorithmic way for your browser to determine if a particular URL is of this type, the Public Suffixes List was created for browsers to change their same-site validation behavior. Hence, `azurewebsites.net` is listed on the [Public Suffixes List](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat).

> So, for sites on the Public Suffixes List a request from
>   `my-site.azurewebsites.net` to `your-site.azurewebsites.net` would be
>   considered cross-site.

Comment: Do you know whether this is only true if the cookie domain is set to `.mysite.com` or is it always true for any (public suffix + 1) combo even if the cookie domain is not set and thus defaults to the issueing host name?

Comment: I realize you're (almost certainly) only the messenger, but the PSL seems an odd way of handling the `my-site.azurewebsites.net` problem. If I wanted to create a portal that allowed `user1.myportal.azurewebsites.net` and `user2.myportal.azurewebsites.net` to use it, but not see each others cookies, presumably I'd have to register `myportal.azurewebsites.net` on that list (not to mention browsers having to scan 13k+ lines to check access). Off the top of my head, specifying a _required-depth-match_ level (4 in the above case) when setting the cookie would seem better...

Comment: Does providing  Domain property can have effect on what considers as same site? If server sends: `Set-Cookie: foo=bar; Domain=site1.example.com; SameSite=strict`, does it means then that `site2.example.com` is still considered as same site?

Comment: The more I learn about web browsers, the more I die inside.

Comment: Agreed. They are terrifying and amazing things. These are things based on standards. Imagine all of the complexities hidden in the non-standardized functionality.

Answer (score 17):

Let me explain the [specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-03#section-5.2).

The [definition of `"same-site"`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-03#section-5.2) is :

> A request is "same-site" if its target's URI's origin's **registered
> domain** is an exact match for the request's client's **"site for
> cookies"**, or if the request has no client.  The request is otherwise
> "cross-site".

> For a given request ("request"), the following algorithm returns
> "same-site" or "cross-site":

> 1. If "request"'s client is "null", return "same-site".

> 2. Let "site" be "request"'s client's **"site for cookies"** (as defined
>    in the following sections).

> 3. Let "target" be the **registered domain** of "request"'s current url.

> 4. If "site" is an exact match for "target", return "same-site".

> 5. Return "cross-site".

As you can see, the core is to compare `site for cookies` with `registered domain`.

Let's start from [`registered domain`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-03#section-2.3).

> An origin's **"registered domain"** is the origin's host's public suffix
> plus the label to its left.  That is, for "https://www.example.com",
> the public suffix is "com", and the registered domain is
> "example.com".  This concept is defined more rigorously in [PSL](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-03#ref-PSL), and
> is also known as "effective top-level domain plus one" (eTLD+1).

> [PSL] "Public Suffix List", n.d., https://publicsuffix.org/list/.

However, as you can see in https://publicsuffix.org/list/, `github.io` is also in the list which means it is a public suffix. Thus, the `registered domains` of `https://me.github.io` and `https://you.github.io` are `me.github.io` and `you.github.io` while the `registered domains` of `https://me.example.com` and `https://you.example.com` are both `example.com`.

The reason is that `github.io` is in the https://publicsuffix.org/list/ while `example.com` is not in the https://publicsuffix.org/list/.

Let's keep moving. So, what is the `"site for cookies"`?

We can find it's [definition here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-03#section-5.2.1)

> The URI displayed in a user agent's address bar is the only security
> context directly exposed to users, and therefore the only signal
> users can reasonably rely upon to determine whether or not they trust
> a particular website. **The registered domain of that URI's origin**
> represents the context in which a user most likely believes
> themselves to be interacting.  We'll label this domain the **"top-level
> site"**.

> For a document displayed in a top-level browsing context, we can stop
> here: the document's "site for cookies" is the top-level site.

> For documents which are displayed in nested browsing contexts, we
> need to audit the origins of each of a document's ancestor browsing
> contexts' active documents in order to account for the "multiple-
> nested scenarios" described in Section 4 of [RFC7034].  A document's
> "site for cookies" is the top-level site if and only if the document
> and each of its ancestor documents' origins have the same registered
> domain as the top-level site.  Otherwise its "site for cookies" is
> the empty string.

> Given a Document ("document"), the following algorithm returns its
> "site for cookies" (either a registered domain, or the empty string):

> 1. Let "top-document" be the active document in "document"'s
>    browsing context's top-level browsing context.

> 2. Let "top-origin" be the origin of "top-document"'s URI if "top-
>    document"'s sandboxed origin browsing context flag is set, and
>    "top-document"'s origin otherwise.

> 3. Let "documents" be a list containing "document" and each of
>    "document"'s ancestor browsing contexts' active documents.

> 4. For each "item" in "documents":

> ```
>   1.  Let "origin" be the origin of "item"'s URI if "item"'s
> ```

```
       sandboxed origin browsing context flag is set, and "item"'s
       origin otherwise.
```

> ```
>   2.  If "origin"'s host's registered domain is not an exact match
> ```

```
       for "top-origin"'s host's registered domain, return the empty
       string.
```

> 5. Return "top-origin"'s host's registered domain.

The related definitions are listed above.

We can end with an example.

For instance, a request from `https://me.github.io` to `https://you.github.io` is `cross site` if the URI displayed in the user agent's address bar is `https://me.github.io`.

However, a request from `https://me.example.com` to `https://you.example.com` is `same site` if the URI displayed in the user agent's address bar is `https://me.example.com`.

The difference is that the `registered domains` of `https://me.github.io` and `https://you.github.io` are `me.github.io` and `you.github.io` while the `registered domains` of `https://me.example.com` and `https://you.example.com` are both `example.com`.

Answer (score 2):

The target URI’s “registered domain” must be an “exact match” for the request’s “site for cookies”.

You know what a “registered domain” is: The domain name you can buy or rent, i.e. one level below the [public suffix](https://publicsuffix.org/list/).

The “site for cookies“ is usually the “registered domain” as well – here, of the request. This is true when the document is “in a top-level browsing context”, i.e. for most sites. Only for documents “in nested browsing contexts”, an additional requirement is that “the document and each of its ancestor documents’ origins have the same registered domain as the top-level site”.

**In short:** Subdomains don’t count. You have to compare the registrable domains.

Source: [draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-03](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-03)